# Copying from one non power of 2 texture to another in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es, render-to-texture

I am using OpenGL ES 2.0 on iOS .

I have the following code to copy from a smaller texture to within a larger texture; everything goes through and there are no glGetError() .  Yet when I read pixels back it seems that nothing got written and the original texture is unmodified.

So I was wondering if its ok to use Texture Unit 0 to do the copy; or is the frame buffer implicitly using texture unit 0 when I ask it to use a texture for its color render buffer? In other words does glFramebufferTexture2D tie up the texture unit 0?  Do I need to use texture unit 1 instead for the fromTexture ?

Or is there some other problem with the code that could be causing it to trip?

```
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, toTextureImage.name );

// Set the texture parameters for a non power of 2;
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0 );

// Generate a new FBO. It will contain the texture as the color render buffer (color attachment).
GLuint offscreenFrameBuffer;

glGenFramebuffers( 1, &offscreenFrameBuffer );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, offscreenFrameBuffer );

// Bind the texture to the FBO; Question ?  With this use the texture unit 0?
glFramebufferTexture2D( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, toTextureImage.texture.name, 0 );

// Test if everything failed
GLenum status = glCheckFramebufferStatus( GL_FRAMEBUFFER );

if( status != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE )
{
    DebugLog( @"failed to make complete framebuffer object %x", status );
    return ;
}

// Bind the FBO; it is already bound;
// glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, offscreenFrameBuffer );

glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, fromTextureImage.name );

BoundingBox uvBounds;

uvBounds.xmin = 0.0;
uvBounds.xmax = 1.0;
uvBounds.ymin = 0.0;
uvBounds.ymax = 1.0;

Vector2 renderUVs[6];
quadsFromBoundingBox( &uvBounds, renderUVs );

BoundingBox verticesBounds;

verticesBounds.xmin = toPos->v[0];
verticesBounds.xmax = toPos->v[0] + fromTextureImage.imageSize->v[0];
verticesBounds.ymin = toPos->v[1];
verticesBounds.ymax = toPos->v[1] + fromTextureImage.imageSize->v[1];

Vector2 renderVertices[6];
quadVerticesFromBoundingBox( &verticesBounds, renderVertices );

[ self prepareToDraw ];

// Tell the shader what the UVs are ...
[ self setTexture0UVs:renderUVs ];

// use linear filtering for non power of 2
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );

// set the default color to use
[ self setColor4b:&colorRGB_White ];

// Tell the shader what the vertices are;
[ self setVerticesVector2s:renderVertices ];

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ZERO);

glDrawArrays( GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6 );

glDisable(GL_BLEND);

// Unbind the framebuffer;
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0 );
glDeleteFramebuffers( 1, &offscreenFrameBuffer );
```

Answer (score 1):

Framebuffer attachment binding is nothing to do with the texture unit; they are totally independent concepts in the API.